# PhoneGap Ajax call to HTTPS server with self-signed certificate fails

Tags: ajax, post, ssl, https, cordova

I am relatively new to phonegap and I have recently set up HTTPS/SSL on my windows apache server with a self signed certificate and am trying to make an HTTPS ajax post request. The request works fine when ran in a browser but fails when run within phonegap. I tried setting android:debuggable to false but that did not fix the issue. I have also done some research and it appears that phonegap does support HTTPS ajax requests so I am confused as to why the request is failing.

Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: I've come across this issue too. The only problem is that your webservice is self signed. If and when you get a correctly signed cert this will not be an issue. For now you can just use HTTP to test.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was the self signed cert and it is not an issue with a correctly signed cert.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a quote from Joe Bowser who wrote the code to allow self signed certs on PhoneGap Android:

> 1. If you are doing development: android:debuggable="true" in the manifest, you should allow the browser to request data from servers
>      with a self-signed or bad SSL cert
> 2. If you are releasing an application, you should remove the android:debuggable="true" (Android Market won't let you release with
>      this on anyway) and you will NOT be able to send data to a server with
>      a bad SSL cert
> 3. If you don't have this flag set, the default will be what the default is now, which is that you won't be able to send data to
>      servers with a self-signed cert

So it seems like you should be able to do what you want by setting android:debuggable="true". If that isn't working for you we'll need to get a reproduction scenario from you, the version of PhoneGap and the version of Android you are using.

Probably best to raise a bug in Jira for us:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aissues-panel

Comment: is there any solution for iOS?

Comment: @charles: [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9658166/814416) worked the best for me.

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours on this issue until I found that there is a [quick and dirty fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20037373/336235) possible. It involves overriding `CordovaWebViewClient` to ignore certificate errors.