# Ajax https call in ios using PhoneGap not working?

Tags: iphone, ios, ajax, cordova, cross-platform

I could not able to do https POST call using ajax from ipad/iphone. Actually I am trying to call this in my PhoneGap application.

Could you please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have not stated the kind of certificate on the server. I suspect that it is self signed. I have also had the same problem. 
Doing Ajax calls to a server with self signed certificated is NOT possible and this is a SDK limitation. You must write an Objective C plugin to go around this.

Comment: Great Jordan ! You are right I am using self signed certificate. Looking around to write a plugin to do the need. Thanks for your time and answer.

Comment: http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/1012434483/phonegap-and-iphone-development  -- see if this link can help.It is for older versions.   P.S. nt my blog just found it related.

Answer (score 36):

Did you try to add this at the end of you AppDelegate.m file

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES; 
}
@end
```

Comment: great one :) it helped me a lot.

Comment: ..almost... :( Interestingly it works when I use the IOS simulator, but on the IPad I still cannot access my REST api via https and a self-signed certificate.

Comment: Great, except that it's private API. Anyway it's for local use I guess, so no problem.

Comment: This is really a horribly insecure idea, you have essentially disabled SSL checks for bad servers or servers who have been hijacked and had their cert replaced by a bad copy (man in the middle attacks).

Answer (score 3):

TDeBailleul,

Your code seems to work for an anonymous area of the web server, but doesn't work for myself in an Authorized area (cgi.auth_user) with Basic/NTLM authorization.

**PhoneGap for iOS FAQ**
Q. Can I do AJAX with servers that have self-signed certificates?
A. No, this is a iOS SDK limitation with UIWebview. You'll have to write an Objective-C plugin.

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/41631150/PhoneGap%20for%20iOS%20FAQ