# Randomly getting AJAX status 0

Tags: ajax, cordova

I have a PhoneGap project and lately I've been been hitting a lot of random "status 0" results.  I can literally try the same end-point 10 times in a row, passing the same post parameters, and the status will flip between a 200 and a 0.  In both cases, the results return almost instantly - it is not a timeout issue.

I'm using PhoneGap in iOS, if the platform is a factor.  Does anyone have any ideas on where to start looking?

FYI - I implemented the tip at [Ajax https call in ios using PhoneGap not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276643/ajax-https-call-in-ios-using-phonegap-not-working/9843315#9843315).  At first I thought it helped, but perhaps it was just a run of good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly normal to get a status of 0 when requesting a URL over AJAX. Since some browsers will return a 0 on a CORS request but since you are doing your request from the file:// protocol CORS does not apply. When I do a AJAX request I take 200 and 0 as a success.

Comment: I ran with your feedback and investigated further.  It looks like the status 0 doesn't return any data, so I can't treat it as a success.  Your response did spark an idea, however - I didn't know that status 0 was triggered by a server response.  I thought it always had to do with the web client blocking the outbound call!  I did further research and found that I was having a 'random' PHP Warning message in my JSON result.  Apparently AJAX considers this a Status 0 instead of a corrupt Status 200.  So you're right - a 0 is ok; I should just consider it a corrupt success.