# SAML 2.0 Single Log Out (SLO) issue with iOS & PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, saml-2.0

I am using Phonegap and jQuery AJAX calls to perform logout like below

```
$.ajax({
url: logoutURL,
type: "POST",
data: {},
cache: false,
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){........},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){                

        alert("Logout Failed.");

    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    enableAllButtons(); 
}
});
```

the logout URL is a SAML 2.0 Single Log Out (SLO) URL. I have tested this on Android it is working perfectly fine. But when I tried the SLO on ios specifically iPad ios 6.1.3 it will fail and it returns me with a http 0.

I just found out from the IDP log that for android it has a warning of "Client Certificate error, IP address" but it will then automatically attempt to create outgoing SSL connection without trusted certificates. on the other hand, on iOS it does not continue the connection after the signed assertion was issued.

How can I get this solved or is there a way for me to bypass the cert problem?

All advice are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem which was that iOS is unable to call https ajax calls to self signed certificate. It seems it is a SDK limitation and you will need a plugin or add the following codes in your appdelegate.m

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)

+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES; 
}
@end
```

I found this post helpful [Ajax https call in ios using PhoneGap not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276643/ajax-https-call-in-ios-using-phonegap-not-working/9843315#9843315)

Then it worked magically.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds non-standard so I think your best shot is to talk to the IDP provider.