# How to use a self-signed certificate with PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, https, cordova

I want to bring up a quite old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276643/ajax-https-call-in-ios-using-phonegap-not-working) on how to enable phonegap to be able to communicate with a server via https using a self-signed certificate.

The solution proposed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9658166/237690) allows me to access the server via the IOS simulator. Interestingly, after building the app via PhoneGap build, nothing seems to have changed and I'm still not able to access the server via the IPad.

Any idea why it might work at the IOS simulator and not on the IPad? Any suggestions for a work around? I'm a bit reluctant to try this [plugin](http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/blog/post/1012434483/phonegap-and-iphone-development#.Ucx3CvZNvjg), since it is three years old and I have no clue what it is doing..