# How to perform Ajax call with the HTTPS protocol in Phonegap Android?

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to Android. I am developing an app in Phonegap and implemented ajax calls to   communicate with the server using the HTTPS protocol. It's working fine when I set debuggable to true in the manifest file. If I change it to false, it's not working. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web service you're using needs to have a valid cert, one that is not self signed. Otherwise SSL will fail.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977226/phonegap-ajax-call-to-https-server-with-self-signed-certificate-fails)

Answer (score 0):

Another issue which occurs in Android 4.0+ (but not in older versions like 2.3)... is you have to manually set the Authorization header in before send.  Using the new username: password: options added in jQuery 1.7 do NOT work.

The example below illustrates what you have to do.
Note: This requires the base64 jquery plugin.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "https://yoururl,
            type: method,
            dataType: 'json',
            // username: username,  // Doesn't work on ANDROID
            // password: password,  // Doesn't work on ANDROID
            beforeSend: function (xhr)
            {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + $.base64.encode( username + ":" + password ));
            },
            data: options.data,
            success: function(response) {

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
        });
```