# Phonegap, Android getJSON call in release build

Tags: android, cordova

I've got an Android PhoneGap app that makes various calls to services using the getJSON method.  When debugging, or installing the debug APK onto a device, all of these calls work without issue. When I create the APK for release and install on the same device, they start failing.

The code below is an example.  The error logged in the console for the function below is

Login failed : error :  : {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

```
            function getAppServerUrl(org, callBack) {
                console.log('call locator service : ' + org);
                $.getJSON('https://url_removed/loc/locator?id=' + org,
                    function (data) {
                        console.log('getAppServer returned ' + data);
                        appServer = data + '/';
                        callBack();
                    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.error('Login failed : ' + textStatus + 
                           ' : ' + errorThrown + 
                           ' : ' + JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    });
            }
```

I have checked the config.xml contains the access origin

```
<access origin="https://url_removed"/>
```

I have even added a wildcard one

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

Thanks in advance,,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've done some more digging and found my answers.  The first clue was that changing from https to http seemed to cure it.

From there I found a couple of relevant posts.  It seems the server I'm calling has not got the SSL certificate installed correctly.  As the post below says, the server appears fine on a desktop, but fails on Android browsers.

[Certificate is trusted by PC but not by Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340298/certificate-trusted-on-pc-but-not-in-android)

The problem did not show until the signed release version of the app, as Phonegap allows bad certificates when in debug.

[PhoneGap Ajax call to HTTPS server with self-signed certificate fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977226/phonegap-ajax-call-to-https-server-with-self-signed-certificate-fails/8977318#8977318)

Hopefully this info may help others with a similar issue.