# XMLHTTPrequest and CrossWalk Android ( edit ..after i found a solution !)

Tags: android, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

original post: ( before fix )..
I develop an application (transformer.html) with XDK (ThreeJS and WebGL )  to control another application. The communication is established via a WebService (VB ASP.Net). The first version of this transformer.html had **NO WebGL** neither crosswalk. In debug and emulator-mode all is fine. Also compiled as a legacy hybrid mobile APK and published to my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 without any problems. The problems pop up when I implement **CrossWalk AND XMLHTTPRequest** in my app.

The same origin policy seems not to be a problem. I placed this on web server side (in web.config).

```
<webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
 </webServices>
```

As said - the constellation Transformer-APP on Tablet -- WebService ---  TargetWebApplication is **running perfectly** in my **local network**!

**The Problem:**

The problem I run into came up with **implementing a simple WebGL graphic.** Everything is running perfectly in simulation and debug, and when I just run this in a Firefox browser. But when I build an APK this combination (CrossWalk & XMLHTTPRequest) **fails**!

***kristina/14.03.15:** it´s working now. i consequently used this XDK-example: https://github.com/gomobile/sample-webgl-threejs

i took my httprequest in  and it was working fine!*

Before:
XMLHTTPRequest (or even the POST via jQuery!) work fine under **Android Legacy build**. I could make the APK running but there was **no Crosswalk** WebGL graphic **visible** on my app. So HTTP Post was OK, but not Crosswalk. I´m wondering if it is possible to build a legacy App with Crosswalk. Even with the XDK's own Crosswalk demo, I was not able to build as a hybrid Legacy APK.

**CrossWalk** was OK on my app when I **build with CrossWalk** for Android, but, in this case, XMLHTTPRequest seems not possible. My connection to the WebService fails; I got a 404. But, as I said, all communication should be there, as in other modes (legacy, emulation, browser, whatever...), its working.

***kristina/14.03.15:*** XDK recomment to build it in Android/Crosswalk. This is working NOW. The trick is to set specific host parameters in the build section!

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

( handle with care. e.g. reduce this to limited hosts! my setup only is working in my smal local environment. This way it´s ok for me  )

those info was very helpful during the errorTracking:

*https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/adding-special-build-options-to-your-xdk-cordova-app-with-the-intelxdk-config-additions-xml-file
https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/using-the-cordova-for-android-ios-etc-build-option
http://www.ilinsky.com/articles/XMLHttpRequest/#usage

This was NOT very helpful - as in XDK/cordova/Crosswalk the manifest.json seem not effect anything(!?):

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/manifest/content_security_policy.html

As so soften it was the same-origine topic i struggled..

Many Thanks to Paul (Intel) who gave me the final hint :-)

Now the construction
**CrossWalk - WebGL - XMLHttpRequest - Webservice**   is working perfect

*

My Setup:

- XDK1826 (latest release I got automatically!)
- Samsung Galaxy Tab 3

If you need more info  please let me know.

THIS code is running after the fixes:

```
main.js::

    /*jslint browser:true, devel:true, white:true, vars:true, eqeq:true */
/*global THREE:false, requestAnimationFrame:false*/

/*
 * Based on http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_cube.html
 */
document.addEventListener ('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var camera, scene, renderer;

    var cube, plane;

    var targetRotation = 0;
    var targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;

    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;

    var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    var auto_timer = 0;

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: true, devicePixelRatio: 1 } );
        renderer.setSize (window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild (renderer.domElement);

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (
            70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
        camera.position.y = 150;
        camera.position.z = 500;

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // Cube
        var geometry_cube = new THREE.CubeGeometry (200, 200, 200);

        var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture ('textures/crosswalk.png');//Works on mobile Android NOT in Browser or Intel XDK
        texture.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy ();

        var material_cube = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial ( { map: texture } );

        cube = new THREE.Mesh (geometry_cube, material_cube);
        cube.position.y = 150;
        scene.add( cube );

        // Plane
        var geometry_plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry (180, 180);
        geometry_plane.applyMatrix (new THREE.Matrix4 ().makeRotationX (-Math.PI / 2));

        var material_plane = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial ( { color: 0xde613e } );

        plane = new THREE.Mesh (geometry_plane, material_plane);
        scene.add (plane);

        document.addEventListener ('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
        document.addEventListener ('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);
        document.addEventListener ('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false);

        // Generic setup

        window.addEventListener ('resize', onWindowResize, false);
    }

    function onWindowResize () {
        windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix ();
        renderer.setSize (window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }

    function stopAutoRotate () {
        if (auto_timer)
            window.clearTimeout (auto_timer);
        auto_timer = window.setTimeout (startAutoRotate, 1000);
    }

    function startAutoRotate () {
        auto_timer = 0;
    }

    function animate () {
        requestAnimationFrame (animate);
        plane.rotation.y = cube.rotation.y += (targetRotation - cube.rotation.y) * 0.05;
        if (auto_timer === 0) {
            targetRotation += 0.025;
        }
        renderer.render (scene, camera);
    }

    function onDocumentMouseDown (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.addEventListener ('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
        document.addEventListener ('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
        document.addEventListener ('mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false);
        mouseXOnMouseDown = e.clientX - windowHalfX;
        targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;
        stopAutoRotate ();
    }

    function onDocumentMouseMove (e) {
        mouseX = e.clientX - windowHalfX;
        targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown +
            (mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown) * 0.02;
        stopAutoRotate ();
    }

    function onDocumentMouseUp (e) {
        document.removeEventListener ('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
        document.removeEventListener ('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
        document.removeEventListener ( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false);
        stopAutoRotate ();
    }

    function onDocumentMouseOut (e) {
        document.removeEventListener ('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
        document.removeEventListener ('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
        document.removeEventListener ('mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false);
        stopAutoRotate ();
    }

    function onDocumentTouchStart (e) {
        if (e.touches.length === 1) {
            e.preventDefault ();

            miniHttpTest();
            getSphereParametersWSxhr();

            mouseXOnMouseDown = e.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
            targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;
            stopAutoRotate ();
        }
    }

    function onDocumentTouchMove (e) {
        if (e.touches.length === 1) {
            e.preventDefault ();
            mouseX = e.touches[0].pageX - windowHalfX;
            targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown +
                (mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown) * 0.05;
            stopAutoRotate ();
        }
    }
});

function XHRObject() {
    var xhr;

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onerror = function () {};
    xhr.onstart = function () {};
    xhr.success = function () {};

    return xhr;
}


function getSphereParametersWSxhr() {
    var url = "http://192.444.2.444/transporter.asmx/getVideoCubeParameters";
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = "";

    console.log(xhr);
    alert("-----------------------------   getSphereParametersWSxhr - before open POST : " + xhr);
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // forbidden xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    alert("after open POST : " + xhr);

    try {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

            alert("xhr.readyState == " + xhr.readyState + " xhr.status == " + xhr.status + " xhr.statusText: " + xhr.statusText + " xhr.responseText" + xhr.responseText);

            if (xhr.readyState == 2 && xhr.status == 404) {
                console.log("404 page not found: " + xhr);
                alert("404 page not found: " + xhr);
            }
            if (xhr.readyState == 3) {
                console.log("ready state 3: " + xhr.statusText + " " + xhr.status);
                alert("ready state 3: " + xhr.statusText + " " + xhr.status);
            }
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) { //&& xhr.status == 200
                console.log("ready state 4: " + xhr.statusText + " " + xhr.responseText);
                alert("ready state 4: " + xhr.statusText + " " + xhr.responseText);

                var erg1 = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("videoCubeSizeX")[0].textContent;
                var stringList = erg1.split(";");
                console.log(erg1);
                alert("videoCubeSizeX: " + erg1);
                alert(xhr.responseText);

            }

        }
        xhr.send(params);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("XHR Post : " + e);
        alert("XHR Post : " + e);
    }
}

function miniHttpTest() {
    alert("miniHttpTest: mit GET ");

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://crosswalk-project.org/", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
           alert("ready state 4: " + xhr.statusText + " " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: stack did not take my code when i post my question  here it is :

Comment: unfortunately stack did not take my javascript code here.. my code is also available on www.pimpyourparty.de..the litte cube and with ff you easy can see my script.. thanks for any help kristina

Comment: Kristina, welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to add code here, you need to paste it directly into your question, highlight it, and press Ctrl + K. There is no support on this website for uploading attachments.

Comment: TylerH thank u so much for this hint  ..i tried before ctrl-K ..but i didnt highlight it...some times i´m soo "blond"