# Fire HTTPS requests

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, cordova-4

I have an android project which uses `cordova`. I am firing some `http` requests. It works fine. But when I generated signed apk, the firing is done as `https` requests. Android studio does not support this type of requests. How can I find an alternate solution for this? I tried [Phonegap Android app ajax requests to HTTPS fail with status 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036260/phonegap-android-app-ajax-requests-to-https-fail-with-status-0?answertab=oldest#tab-top) but this answer is outdated as `Cordova 4.0.0` does not have this method .Please help me out.

Comment: Your SSL certificate is not trusted by the device, so use another SSL certificate or don't use SSL

Answer (score 0):

@Nevin, an alternative in HTML5 is to leave out the *http* (or *https*).

Instead of this:

https://domain.com/request/

Write:

//domain.com/request/

This is support by many browsers. It is a way to fix a common problem, where the javascript is on a secure connection, but the webpage is not.